# Auto switch between two DC power sources, depending on battery level

Tags: power-supply, raspberry-pi, solar-energy

I'm looking for a way to use my Raspberry Pi on solar power when my solar-charged battery has enough power, and switch to the usual electric power grid when my battery reaches a certain level.

I don't know what I should do. I'm not good at all with electronics, so the best for me would be to buy something already built, but if there is no way to do that I will have to build something myself.

I'm asking for help because I think it's a bit tricky:

The goal would be to switch to the power grid when my battery is low, like 10%, and switch back when it has been recharged far enough, like to 50%.

For now my battery is an external battery for a mobile phone able to output multiple voltages from USB C PD, but I plan on building a battery with 18650 cells and a BMS, which would be easier to monitor (I think).

Since I don't have a lot of things plugged into the power (Raspberry Pi 4 and 3 hard drives, I think this uses 10 W in total), I'd like to do something inexpensive; it's not for a full house.

Comment: Why not just switch to battery when AC power is down? Is there a reason to over-complicate things?

Comment: @Andyaka I want to do the contrary: be on battery most of the time, because the battery is charged with a solar panel, switch to ac when the battery is low

Comment: Power through two diodes (one from each source), and make the mains power input just a bit higher than the empty battery voltage, perhaps?

Comment: _"I plan on building a battery with 18650 cells and a BMS, which would be easier to monitor (I think)." - how do you intend to produce 5V for the Pi from this battery, and how do you intend to charge it from solar?

Comment: Maybe check for something already made. Like the Adafruit https://www.adafruit.com/product/4755 Only things is, doesn’t meet your heavy power demands…

Comment: @BruceAbbott I have a buck boost to reduce tension to 12V to charge the battery and another buck boost to keep it to 12V when plugged into the battery, this 12V is plugged to a usb hub where the raspberry pi is plugged with other devices, and also a hard drive which requires 12V, it already works with my current battery

Comment: @user253751 the battery is the main source, power grid would be the backup

I'm not sure to understand the diodes thing, could you please tell me what it would do exactly . thanks !

Comment: @RemyHx the adafruit is good to prioritize the solar panel and use the battery as backup, but doesn't handle the usual power grid at all

Comment: Phie if you connect two sources in parallel, a diode in series with each source, the highest voltage source will power the load and the other one will be blocked by its diode. It's a simple way to switch between two power sources, however the diode voltage drop does waste a little power.